# Why doesn't a Playstation 3 controller work out of the box as a USB HID device?

Tags: game-controller, ps3, usb-hid

I want to use a website that uses the Gamepad API (see https://gamepad-tester.com for instance). This website works well with a wired PS3 controller on Chrome on macOS.

However when I plug the controller into a Windows machine, Chrome does not detect it. A Logitech controller that presents itself as an Xbox controller works fine.

I'm pretty sure the PS3 controller is a standard USB HID device, so why doesn't it work out of the box? Sure, there's a simple proprietary handshake for doing Bluetooth pairing, but other than that shouldn't it work like any other gamepad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sony never intended for PlayStation 3 controllers to work on Windows.  Therefore, they did not make device drivers for it.  This does not mean it cannot be done.  There are many [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=use%20a%20ps3%20controller%20on%20pc&oq=use%20a%20ps3&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l6j69i60.10823j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you can Google for to accomplish this.  Here is [one](https://www.pcgamer.com/ps3-controller-on-pc-guide/).

As for the Logitech controller working as an XBox controller, Microsoft does have drivers for XBox controllers on Windows.  Therefore, anything presenting itself as a Windows compatible XBox controller should work.

Just because a device is USB and Windows recognizes it as a certain class of device, doesnt mean it will work out-of-the-box.  Without proper device drivers, Windows will not know what to do with it.

Comment: Thanks. I did try ScpToolkit briefly, as it is the most-recommended software, but it seemed ridiculous, installing like 5 separate programs like a "clean wipe utility", and several sound effects. The complexity of the [removal guide](https://vigem.org/projects/ScpToolkit/ScpToolkit-Removal-Guide/) is asinine. I did not spend time configuring it but out of the box still the controller was not recognized by Chrome.